# jQuery animate - duration not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, duration

js:

```
var time, key, speed, noteTime;
function readTextFile(file) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        var occ = occurrences(allText, "\n", "false");
        var string = allText.split("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < occ; i++) {
          time = string[i].split("{time:");
          time = time[1].split(",key:");
          key = string[i].split(",key:");
          key = key[1].split(",speed:");
          speed = string[i].split(",speed:");
          speed = speed[1].split("}");
          speed = speed[0];
          noteTime = time[0] - 3000;
          if(noteTime < 0) {
            noteTime = 0;
          }
          console.log(noteTime);
          console.log(speed);
          setTimeout(function(){
            $("#test").animate({
              left: "+=100"
            }, speed);
          }, noteTime);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
readTextFile("mercury.myr");
```

html:

```
<div style="height:50px; width:50px; background-color: black; position: relative;" id="test"></div>
```

mercury.myr:

```
{time:7000,key:32,speed:3000}\n
```

..I think it's correct code, but not. 
jQuery animate() is working, but it's not 3000ms.
This is as fast as 500ms ..!
I've changed HTML, CSS, and JS several times, but this is not fixed.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I want to move the #test div at a speed of 3000 ms.

Comment: I wanted to move the #test div at a speed of 3000ms, but the #test div moves at a speed of about 500ms.

Comment: It is the same as 3000.

Comment: it was a debugging question

Comment: do u ask people to debug ur code?

Comment: i suggest, u to delete ur question, since it was not useful based on stackoverflow purposes. people are right, here is not a place for debugging

Answer (score 1):

in the

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $("#test").animate({
              left: "+=100"
            }, speed);
          }, noteTime);
```

replace `speed` with 3000

Comment: Please check the code written in the question.
It is defined by the readTextFile () function.

Comment: Sorry, I solved this problem.
It works by converting the speed to number using the Number function.

Comment: it means that, my answer was helpful :)